# what does it mean by "scene politics"?

Tags: meaning

"Remember the first time you went to a show and saw your favorite band. You wore their shirt, and sang every word. You didn’t know anything about scene politics, haircuts, or what was cool. All you knew was that this music made you feel different from anyone you shared a locker with. Someone finally understood you. This is what music is about."

What does it mean by "scene politics"?

Comment: What is considered "hip|cool|proper" by some imagined arbiters of the subculture.

Comment: "Politics" has its usual, dictionary, meaning (in the sense of "office politics"). "Scene" means the people, community, and subculture related to the specific musical band or artist in question.

Answer (score 4):

[*Scene*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scene#Noun)

> A social environment consisting of an informal, vague group of people with a uniting interest; their sphere of activity; a subculture.

[*Politics:*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/politics#Noun)

> Political maneuvers or diplomacy between people, groups, or organizations, especially involving power, influence or conflict.

In particular *politics* doesn't just refer to the sort of things that affect government policy, but also has a sense referring to the gaining and losing of influence within a group. Think more high school than parliament, though there's plenty of the high-school type of politics involved in the other sort of politics, at every level.

So together it refers to the jockying for position, popularity contests, bitchiness, who-said-what-about-whom and so on occurring in the community that exist around "your favourite band".